# Как не останавливать цикл и использовать потоки в методе

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

У меня на сокете должны производится вычисления которые повторяются в цикле метода main. Мне нужно сделать что бы цикл отработал быстрее. Что бы мы не ждали каждый расчет метода sendToFightCalc, так как не в игрушечном примере там расчет занимает секунд по 30. Как можно реализовать задуманное? Мне не обязательна чтобы main понимал что все расчеты сделаны, я добавлю счетчик и клиент будет обращаться к сокету с вопросом готовы ли все данные.

```
class ExapleTnh():
    fight_result = {}

    def addFightResult(self, hero, enemy, result):
        self.fight_result[hero[0]] = {}
        self.fight_result[hero[0]]['enemy'] = enemy[0]

        self.fight_result[hero[0]]['win1'] = result[0]
        self.fight_result[hero[0]]['win2'] = result[1]

    def sendToFightCalc(self, hero, enemy):
        #os.chdir("C:\\example")
        #send_to_sub_proc = subprocess.run(f'java -cp blabla.jar hero "{hero}" enemy "{enemy}"',capture_output=True)
        #response = send_to_sub_proc.stdout.decode('utf-8').split()[2]
        response = [33, 25]
        return response

    def thread_navernoe(self, hero, enemy_hero):
        result = self.sendToFightCalc(hero[1], enemy_hero[1])
        self.addFightResult(hero, enemy_hero, result)

    def main(self):
        all_heroes = [['Nick1', 'Weapon'],['Nick2', 'Weapon'],['Nick3', 'Weapon'],['Nick4', 'Weapon']]
        for hero in all_heroes:
            #print('hero: ', hero)
            for enemy_hero in all_heroes:
                #print('enemy_hero: ', enemy_hero)
                if {hero[0]} != {enemy_hero[0]}:
                    self.thread_navernoe(hero, enemy_hero)
                    
        return self

aa = ExapleTnh().main()
print(aa.fight_result)
```

Comment: @Интик к сожалению я не представляю как это сделать и роль флагов в пайтоне. Можно пример..?

Comment: вам надо написать, как вызвать поток? у вас в примере нет потока, какие флаги

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потоки можно добавить в массив и в цикле подождать пока каждый завершится.

```
import threading
import time

class ExapleTnh():
    threads = []
    fight_result = {}

    def addFightResult(self, hero, enemy, result):
        self.fight_result[hero[0]] = {}
        self.fight_result[hero[0]]['enemy'] = enemy[0]

        self.fight_result[hero[0]]['win1'] = result[0]
        self.fight_result[hero[0]]['win2'] = result[1]

    def sendToFightCalc(self, hero, enemy):
        # os.chdir("C:\\example")
        # send_to_sub_proc = subprocess.run(f'java -cp blabla.jar hero "{hero}" enemy "{enemy}"',capture_output=True)
        # response = send_to_sub_proc.stdout.decode('utf-8').split()[2]
        response = [33, 25]
        return response

    def thread_navernoe(self, hero, enemy_hero):
        result = self.sendToFightCalc(hero[1], enemy_hero[1])
        self.addFightResult(hero, enemy_hero, result)
        time.sleep(2)

    def main(self):
        all_heroes = [['Nick1', 'Weapon'], ['Nick2', 'Weapon'], ['Nick3', 'Weapon'], ['Nick4', 'Weapon']]
        for hero in all_heroes:
            for enemy_hero in all_heroes:
                if {hero[0]} != {enemy_hero[0]}:
                    my_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.thread_navernoe, args=(hero, enemy_hero,))
                    my_thread.start()
                    self.threads.append(my_thread)#Добавляем поток
        #Проверяем все ли потоки отработали
        for my_thread in self.threads:
            my_thread.join()
        return self
    
aa = ExapleTnh().main()
print(aa.fight_result)
```